# Ubuntu install on disk with Windows 7 UEFI

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, uefi

When I'm trying to install Ubuntu on computer with UEFI and Windows 7, I see no partitions!
But when I'm running Ubuntu in live mode file system detect all partitions right (screenshot below). What should I do to finally install Ubuntu?
There are few questions with my problem in Google, but instructions didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Problem fixed. To fix problem you must fix partition with Fixparts utility (fixparts \.\physicaldriveХ where X is disk number).

Comment: We expect more then a link to an external site.  We also expect that source to be English, and if its not, for you to translate it for us.

Comment: My answer is complete - to fix problem you must fix partition with Fixparts (fixparts \\.\physicaldriveХ where X is disk number). What about expectations, I also expect assistance when asked a question. Say thanks that I am not too lazy to help others and to write solution.

Comment: Your answer does not contain that information so its not actually complete.  Its not that we are lazy we just didn't know the answer or more likely anyone that knew the answer didn't read the question within the 15 hours you gave it.  All you have to do is modify the answer not to be just a link to an external website and I would remove the downvote.